Python sockets and windows
I got this small script:
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as server_socket:
    server_socket.bind(("127.0.0.1", 5353))

Running it under windows, I got the error PermissionError: [WinError 10013] Der Zugriff auf einen Socket war aufgrund der Zugriffsrechte des Sockets unzulässig
I cannot run it as admin, because I am using an IDE.
Any ideas? TIA!

is there already something bound on port 5353?

The error message is clear, you do not have permission to use that socket. Try a different port. The netstat command should give you a list of all the ports currently being used.

port 5353 is a mdns service and most likely used by your OS. choose a different one, then it works.
you can also check open ports with netstat (e.g. netstat -a -b -p UDP)

choose a different one, then it works ? It's only going to work if the client has permission to connect to a port (on the specified host) that's accepting connections in an unsecured manner

@steinweb is right: Using the port 15353, eveythings works fine. Thank you!

The error usually caused not by permissions but by closed port.
You can try another port, open the closed port or check whether the port is blocked by firewall.
If the port is open and not blocked the IDE can be run as administrator.
You can see the above answers from google: StackOverflow, Github, Streamlit
and others....
